# Xcode doesn't seem to execute my scheme's post-action

Tags: xcode, bash

I'm using Xcode (4.6.2) and my target is an external build tool. The auto generated scheme calls that just fine during build.

On RUNNING, I wanted the scheme to execute another shell script. It wasn't intuitive, but I managed it by setting `/bin/bash` as executable and passing my script as parameter.

The only step left is that I want to execute yet another script AFTER run. And here I thought it'd be easy and just tried to set it as a post-action.

BUT no matter what, I can't get xcode to execute my post-action script.
No matter what it is. I tried `echo hi > /tmp/testfile` even...

I need that post-action to do a bit of cleanup.

---

Again in short:

1. I have a script `build_me` that is my external build tool
2. I have a script `run_me` that I set my scheme to run
3. I have a script `cleanup` that I **want to** have as run post-action

Can't get Xcode to run my post-action script *or any*.

Comment: any progress here? same problem for me.

Comment: reverted parts of edit

Comment: @downvoter: what was wrong/bad

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works on Xcode 5.0, tested, I figure it should work the same in 4.6.2.

#### Post-actions only works when you quit the program from within the program

It will not run when you click on Stop in Xcode, or terminate the program otherwise. For my case, it works when I press CMD-Q while the program is in focus.

#### Using a bash script file for Post-actions

These settings work:
[image]

Comment: when I pass it via the run args.. how is this a post-action script. This Question is not about passing something to my app

Comment: @Daij-Djan Got you, updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: ah yes, and THATS what isn't working for me. ill try put it in again

Answer (score 20):

I suggest you enable logging to a file by adding `exec > /tmp/xcode_build.log 2>&1` to the beginning of your run script phase.

You can than see the log by running `cat /tmp/xcode_build.log` in terminal

This will allow you to print out paths, etc and verify functionality of your scripts.

To print location of the script, you can put following in your post-action:

```
exec > /tmp/my_log_file.txt 2>&1
pwd
```

Comment: This is one of those answers you upvote, forget about after a while and bump into again after a year or so. Wish I could upvote it every time!

Comment: This is brilliant. It's the only way that I've found to be able to debug Post-Actions in an Archive step.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else comes across this, I was using a script file in my project directory and the file did not have the right permissions for the build process to run the script. I did the following in the pre/post action/Run Script area

```
chmod 755 ${PROJECT_DIR}/BuildScripts/IncrementBuildNumber.sh
${PROJECT_DIR}/BuildScripts/IncrementBuildNumber.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit odd, but Archive executes pre and post scripts when called from command line.

So I've made an archive.sh script in my project folder, I pass the name of project ( same as main target - but you can configure that as you like ) as a parameter:

```
xcodebuild clean -project $1.xcodeproj -configuration Release -target $1
xcodebuild archive -project $1.xcodeproj -scheme $1
```

Then I create an "External Build" target name "Archive", with ./archive.sh as script.

When I build this target, Project is cleaned, build and archived.
and post script defined in the scheme is executed

> Just a remark, since I'm building from a shell script, I've removed my
>   post script in the archive scheme, and instead call it after my build
>   commands in my archive.sh script.
>
> This way gives me a better control on working directories, variables
>   and all… It's much more convenient

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Comment: @trojanfoe - The question is why archive post actions are not executed.
My answer is that post actions are executed, not when archive is fired via the menu in xcode, but when it is fired from a script.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the "not working" effect was caused by a directory path lookup failure in my script.

If you run your script at your target's **Build Phases**, A relative directory path like this will work:

```
INFO="MyApp/Info.plist"
```

However in **Pre-Actions** it fails silently.
Instead, you must use an absolute directory path like this:

```
INFO="${PROJECT_DIR}/MyApp/Info.plist"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on programming language you use you can do (it's pseudocode):

```
system( <command> 2>&1 | tee run.log && exit $PIPESTATUS )
```

Comment: sorry don't get it.. where should that help me get it run by Xcode.... please elaborate on the where and how ;)

Comment: ah ok, so you would issue it before the main returns?